# Implementing Map in terms of Reduce in Erlang

Tags: erlang, reduce

I am a beginner in Erlang and I am trying to implement the Map function in terms of the Reduce function . However, I could not picture how you can do it .. I have
tried this so far :

```
reduce(_, Acc, [])     -> Acc;
reduce(Fn,Acc,[Hd|Tl]) -> reduce(Fn,Fn(Acc,Hd),Tl). 

map(F,[])      -> [];
map(F,[Hd|Tl]) -> [reduce(F,F(Hd),[]) | map(F,Tl)].
```

However I am seeing this solution a bit naive . Any help please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use recursion to map a list if you already have a reduce function. You can just pass `(Acc, X) -> [F(X) | Acc]` as the function to `reduce` and then at the end call `lists:reverse` because the list will be created in reverse order.

```
map(F, List) -> lists:reverse(reduce(fun(Acc, X) -> [F(X) | Acc] end, [], List)).
```

We're creating the list in reverse because prepending an element to a list is O(1) unlike appending which is O(n). `lists:reverse` also runs in O(1) which makes this map function O(n). If we did `fun(Acc, X) -> Acc ++ [F(X)] end` and no reverse, that'll be O(n^2).

Comment: I think you ment F(X) in the anonymous function .. but thanks regardless :)